# how to change value in a dictionary<int, float>()?

Tags: c#

I think it's more understandable to show my code here.

```
Dictionary<int, float> list = new Dictionary<int, float>();
list.add(0, 0f);

float fValue = 0f;
list.TryGetValue(0, out fValue);
fValue = 10f;
```

this code is incorrect because float data type is not a class. It's a structure.

I want to change the value, "float".

Anyone ideas?

Comment: That code wouldn't even *compile* to start with, because there's no `add` method. It's also misleading to call a dictionary a list, when it's not.

Comment: *list.add(0,0f) - list.Add(0, 0f); and the name "list" is just a name to explain the issue I faced. :)

Comment: Yes, but my point is that a) if you're going to provide demo code, you should make sure it works first; b) if you're trying to *explain* something, then using a misleading variable name goes against your aim. It's worth putting effort into asking good questions with appropriate sample code which makes your question as clear as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change it's value using its index:

```
list[0] = 10f;
```

where `0` is the `Key` and `10f` is the new `Value`.

Answer (score 2):

In *general case*, you can do something like that:

```
if (list.TryGetValue(0, out fValue)) 
  list[0] = 10f;    // <- key 0 exits
else
  list.Add(0, 10f); // <- no such key found
```

When you don't want `fValue` that corresponds to `0` key, you can shorten the code to

```
if (list.ContainsKey(0)) 
  list[0] = 10f;    // <- when key 0 exits
else
  list.Add(0, 10f); // <- no such key found
```